# How to prevent slowdown of portable C# process while user is away?

Tags: c#, windows, performance, headless

I wrote a C# program that runs in the background pretty much flawlessly, but it slows down if the machine is locked and left alone.

It turns an on-board LED on and off every 100 milliseconds, with the 100 milliseconds being timed by a "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)" call.  (This is for a headless system (no keyboard or monitor) that needs to blink to indicate various statuses.)

The problem comes when the system is left alone for a while and the desktop locks... the blinking stops... but if I come back to the machine and login (it's not headless right now) then the LED begins to ramp up and blink at full speed again.

I suspect that Windows might be doing some sort of power management scheme and  slows down the process to conserve power(?).

To be clear, the device never enters a 'sleep' or 'hibernate' state, and the process returns to a normal cadence as soon as I log back in and move the mouse around for a second...  The process is being run as the logged in user using admin rights.

Definitely no anti-virus on this machine.  Resources being used (memory/CPU) are minuscule and basically equal before and after.

Does anyone know how to build or execute a C# process such that it remains running at a normal speed even if the user has locked the desktop and walked away for a few hours?

EDIT: Included Sample Code from Loop:

```
       while (true) {                

            foreach (var step in steps) 
            {
                var mode = step.Mode;
                var millis = step.Millis;
                switch (mode.ToUpper())
                {
                    //Set LED as per Mode Switch
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millis);
            }

            if (!loopForever) {
                //User wanted single pattern and then exit
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Its called a windows service, also, play with your sleep and power management settings if this is a user mode app it is most likely why it stops

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @TheGeneral unless you're being sarcastic, this is not a Windows Service.  If you ARE being sarcastic, well, what was requested was a portable EXE, so a Windows Service is not an option.

Comment: There was no sarcasm, also portable wasnt mentioned. you are right this is seemingly a power management/sleep issue

Comment: Doing a `Thread.Sleep(...)` in a `while (true)` loop is a pretty poor way to go. Perhaps try using timers and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you aren't using a `Timer`?

Comment: Locking the workstation has a strong knack for causing deadlock in programs that use Winforms and create a Form object on a worker thread.  Caused by the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event, it often fires when the active desktop changes and many controls in the toolbox subscribe it.

Comment: @HansPassant Funny thing is  that it IS a Winforms app BUT we deleted the form (and any instantiating code) so that it would be non-blocking when run from the command-line... (i.e., you hit enter, and it spins up in the background but the command prompt returns instantly)

Comment: @mjwills when I use a timer to do the same thing, it is very inconsistent (that is, the timing itself).  If I'm blinking a light every 20ms or using my code, it pretty much looks fine whereas with a Timer it clearly stutters.. speeds up and slows down right from the start even with Realtime/High process priority.

Comment: @Enigmativity not saying my approach isn't a little lazy, but see my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this kind of issue on WPF application by using:

```
var executionState = NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATES.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATES.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(executionState);
```

I hope it can help you. Here is more [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate)